# How to OLS Regress Y on 1/x denominator in R or Python

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation, python

I have a problem where my general equation is $Y = C + 1/(\beta x)$,
where $C$ is a constant.

I want to find a b in OLS fashion to minimize RSS

I have already transformed my equation thus far:
$Y - C = 1/(\beta x)$

Where $Y - C = Y^*$.

So therefore,

$Y^* = 1/(\beta x)$.

If I just plugged this into R or Python, it would estimate $Y^* = \beta(1/x)$.

However, I want $\beta$ to only affect the denominator.

Can anyone give some insight on how to get this done?

For background, the reason I want $\beta$ to only affect the denominator is because I want when $x$ is large, for $1/(\beta x)$ to equal $0$.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Transformed it even further to get

$Y^* = \exp(-\log(b))\exp(-\log(x))$

Would I just regress $Y$ on $\exp(-\log(x))$ to obtain the first element?

Comment: What exactly are you estimating? Do you know the values of C & b already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to estimate the coefficient $\beta$ in the model $Y = C + 1/(\beta X)$, you just need to do one more step in your reformulation:

$Y = C + 1/(\beta X) \\ 
Y-C = 1/(\beta X) \\
\frac{1}{Y-C} = Y^* = \beta X.$

Then, just regress $Y^*$ on $X$ in order to obtain $\beta$.

Comment: This assumes $C$ is known *a priori*. That would be unusual, which is why most of us will await a response to the comment by @gung in order to determine whether this answer is appropriate or misguided.